# nodejs mysql query data to loop array

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

I'm using `nodejs` and `mysql` to retrieve data from database.

I need to get the result like below:

```
var dictionary, set_lang;
                
dictionary = {
    "english": {
        "_availablestorage": "Available Storage",
        "_prayschedule": "Pray Schedule",
        "_mainmenu": "Main Menu",
        "_temperature": "Temperature",
        "_calibration": "Calibration",
        "_mosque": "Mosque"
    },
    "indonesia": {
        "_availablestorage": "Penyimpanan Tersedia",
        "_prayschedule": "Jadwal Sholat",
        "_mainmenu": "Menu Utama",
        "_temperature": "Suhu",
        "_calibration": "Kalibrasi",
        "_mosque": "Masjid"
    }
};
```

This is my code on js file:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_language;', (err, results)=>
{
    //Here I do not know how to do.
    //res.json(results);
});
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bca422/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dictionaryData = [
      { id: 0, language: 'English' },
      { id: 1, language: 'Indonesian' }
    ]
const languageData = [
      {
        language_id: 0,
        key_language: '_availablestorage',
        description: 'Available Storage'
      },
      {
        language_id: 0,
        key_language: '_prayschedule',
        description: 'Pray Schedule'
      },
      {
        language_id: 0,
        key_language: '_mainmenu',
        description: 'Main Menu'
      },
      {
        language_id: 1,
        key_language: '_availablestorage',
        description: 'Tersedia'
      },
      {
        language_id: 1,
        key_language: '_prayschedule',
        description: 'Jadwal'
      },
      {
        language_id: 1,
        key_language: '_mainmenu',
        description: 'Menu Utama'
      }
    ]
```

The response of the query is like this, then the below code will work.

```
const dictionary = {}
dictionaryData.forEach((data) => {
    const setLang = {}
    languageData.forEach((language) => {
       if (data.id === language.language_id) {
         setLang[language.key_language] = language.description
       }
    })
    dictionary[data.language] = setLang
})
console.log(dictionary)
```

The response is:

```
{
  English: {
    _availablestorage: "Available Storage",
    _mainmenu: "Main Menu",
    _prayschedule: "Pray Schedule"
  },
  Indonesian: {
    _availablestorage: "Tersedia",
    _mainmenu: "Menu Utama",
    _prayschedule: "Jadwal"
  }
}
```

Now change foreach loop with your query loop. and it will work.
The [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ghazalehsan/kfLa063e/2/) is attached